# NameError on defining global variable

Tags: python, function, global

I am showing a subsection of the code where i am defining two functions  `defining_polygon_outside_nest` and `defining_polygon_inside_nest`. `err` is an integer whose values ranges from [0,5]. I define `err` as a global variable within these functions and want to use this to add specific values in list `ants_inroi_outsidenest` and `ants_inroi_insidenest`. Whenever i do this, i am getting an error `if for_coordinates_inside_nest((x,y)) is True and err==0:
NameError: global name 'err' is not defined`. **It works fine if i am not using `err` in function `defining_polygon_inside_nest`** Any suggestions to solve this?

```
err = 0
def defining_polygon_outside_nest(tag_data):
    global err
    ants_in_arena = []
    ants_inroi_outsidenest = []
    for id, (x,y) in tag_data:
        ants_in_arena.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_outside_nest((x,y)) is True and err==0:
            ants_inroi_outsidenest.append(id) 
    return ants_inroi_outsidenest


def defining_polygon_inside_nest(tag_data):   
    global err
    ants_in_arenai = []
    ants_inroi_insidenest = []
    for id, (x, y) in tag_data:
        ants_in_arenai.append(id)
        if for_coordinates_inside_nest((x,y)) is True and err==0:
            ants_inroi_insidenest.append(id)
    return ants_inroi_insidenest
```

Comment: You don't appear to ever give `err` a value, yet you try to use it.

Comment: You need to initialize `err` in each function before you use it.

Comment: @VasilisG. it's still gives the same error.